# Moto G - Bricked after update. Constantly booting to CWM

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, stock-android, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G (XT1032). I used to run Cyanogen then Paranoid Android but recently I have returned to stock. Now, being an idiot, I tried to install Lollipop following this guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6C2ulyhy5M). That failed miserably. After hours of panic and chaotic attempts I managed to get into CWM and restore my backup.
The issue is that the phone automatically boots into CWM and if turned off, it would turn on and boot back into CWM.
I cannot find a stock image for Moto G XT1032 GB UK anywhere. Please advise, please help!
The phone just boots into recovery constantly.

Comment: Suggesting to take it to service centre at the earliest. At the moment, it could just a software issue. I had a similar experience with Galaxy s2. Thought I could fix it. Tried too many things. Ended up with a hardware problem which made phone unusable.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Cyanogenmod again, be sure to clear cache, dalvik, data and system